# Connect to server Nautilus paramters

Tags: command-line, mount, nautilus

I'm connecting to my server using the below command in terminal $ sudo mount -t

```
cifs -o "username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

I wonder how I can do the same but using the `Connect to Server` in Nautilus instead of terminal, anyway of doing that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Yes, you can access the share via Connect-to-Server. No, you cannot specify it's mount point. gvfs ( gio ) will automatically mount your share at /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=server-address,share=folder